# jquery ajax call firing twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick

hi people i have this jquery, which makes a call to a page to insertt an email into a news list.

the call is being fired twice, the urls have a strange _ parameter which i have not added the two urls are that are called with 1 click
:

```
http://www.camerich.co.uk/newsletter_add.php?emailtoadd=meeny@dizzyhigh.com&_=1310316941893
http://www.camerich.co.uk/newsletter_add.php?emailtoadd=meeny@dizzyhigh.com&_=1310316941906
```

how do i stop the call from duplicating???

Jquerycode:

```
$('.searchbox_submit').click(function() { // start the click function for news_submit div
        // get the email address that has been entered
        var emailtoadd = $("#emailtoadd").val();
        // set the url to load 
        var loadUrl = "newsletter_add.php?emailtoadd="+emailtoadd;
        // set the status to let the user know we are loading in the data
        $("#newsresponse").empty().html('<img src="/images/site/loadinfo.gif" width="16" height="16" align="absbottom" /> Processing Request...');
        //load in the data
        $.get(loadUrl, {}, function(myData) {
            // add the response to the newsresponse div
            $("#newsresponse").empty().html(myData); 
        }); // end get request
    });//end click function
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="iconthumbs"  style="background-image:url(images/icons/smaller/subscribe_button.jpg)">
        <div id="searchwrapper" name="searchForm">
            <div class="errortxt" id="newsresponse" style="padding:0 0 0 15px;"></div>
            <input type="text" class="searchbox" name="emailtoadd" id="emailtoadd" style="color: #FFF" onClick="this.value='';" onFocus="this.select()" onBlur="this.value=!this.value?'Enter Email To Subscribe':this.value;" value="Enter Email To Subscribe" />
            <input type="image" src="/images/site/1px.gif" class="searchbox_submit" id="news_submit" value="" />
        </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "_" is added by JQuery to get past IE Caching. This contains the time since epoch at which the call was made.

For the example you gave, the times seem to be

```
1310317101270 = Sun, 10 Jul 2011 16:58:21 GMT
1310317079839 = Sun, 10 Jul 2011 16:57:59 GMT
```

Thats about 22 seconds apart. Are you sure they are from the same call?

PS: Used [this](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to convert the epoch to time

Comment: yeah that was just an example of two calls will update the question with the two calls used for 1 click.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`jquery.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)?

```
$('.searchbox_submit').one('click',function(){

//code 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the click function by preventing the default submit action of the input image button:

```
$('.searchbox_submit').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of your code
```

Comment: Then it must be something else in the code other than what you posted in the question. I was able to get your code to run fine in a fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/XmftR/](http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/XmftR/) Note that the fiddle must use jsonp for a get form within jsfiddle but that should not be a factor. Also, I had to remove the style on the email input box so I could see the text.

Comment: Updated the fiddle so input image button would show up: http://jsfiddle.net/XmftR/1/